# How do I install StarCraft 1.18 on Wine with 64-bit Linux?

Tags: pc, linux, starcraft, wine

I'm trying to install the free StarCraft 1.8 on Linux using Wine.

When I try to run the installer I receive a message:

> ".../StarCraft-Setup.exe" not supported on this system

Do I need to install the 32-bit version of Wine for it to run?

---

Update, after installing Wine 32 bit I can run it, but now I have this error message:

```
00e1:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk "ClientSdk.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installed Wine-staging 6.6 and the game is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this a lot, but ultimately it worked for me out-of-the-box when I tried installing it using https://lutris.net/.

I've installed both the Battle.net launcher and StarCraft Remastered (they exist in the Lutris database already) and it prompted me to install a bunch of "vulkan" things and other related drivers and addons, but it did all by itself and then the launcher just worked.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, visit [WineHQ's AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org).  It's got all sorts of useful information about running programs under Wine.  Support for [Starcraft 1.18+](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35171) is currently listed as "garbage" (doesn't run), but the rating history suggests that if you can get a copy of Wine 3.15, it should work without trouble.

Comment: I'm using Wine 5.